# How can I create or update type entries via REST API request?

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I have an Action built with AOG + Dialogflow that needs to be migrated to the new Actions Builder. But I'm struggling to find a REST API endpoint where I could create or update the types entries as we do with the Dialogflow entity entries. I didn't find the endpoint on Actions Builder docs, so I wondered if it is even possible.

Actions Builder REST API docs:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/api/reference/rest

Dialogflow Rest API docs: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.entityTypes.entities/batchUpdate

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating the Entities for an entire project, you need to do that along with updating the project. See the [projects.draft.write](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/api/reference/rest/v2/projects.draft/write) API endpoint for more details.

One alternative, however, is to update Entities for a particular session. Usually this is done in conjunction with [selection prompts](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-selection) but it can be done in general. With this, your webhook would set the `typeOverrides` field in the [session](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/fulfill#Session) field of the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great! If an answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.